# sugar CRM get_relationships query issue

Tags: sugarcrm

How to pass query for multiple columns search query in sugar CRM get_relationships soap api? 
I passed related_module_query as: "accounts.name like 'abc' OR accounts.phone_office  like 'abc'

If I search either by name only or by phone only its working correct but if I merge both like above it is pulling all records.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the inner working this has a previous query and joins your query with an AND clause.
Have you tried using parenthesis like this?

```
"(accounts.name like 'abc' OR accounts.phone_office like 'abc')"
```

Hope it helps!